# php: comparing string with boolean value

Tags: php, compare

Please explain me why in php 8:

```
"0" == false // true
"00" == true // true but "00" == 0 is true!
"0.0" == true // true
```

I was trying to understand the principle of variable type conversion

Comment: Can you provide the function with you get the boolan resoult? Anyway "00" is a string not a number, so it's ok to get a different resoult compare to 0.

Comment: var_dump("00" == 0); // bool(true)

Comment: Comparing `"00" == 0` is not the same as `"00" == true`

Comment: Also there's a [special page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) with details about type comparisons. Have you read it?

Comment: i can't see logic: why ("0" == false) is true but ("00" == true) is true too??

Comment: @AndreyDeveloper Any math operation will return you 00 and "00" is a string, when you dump a string he get the binary value, for definition false is equal to zero or "0" the same for "0.0" is a string, if you convert to decimali 0.0 will be false

Comment: This clear to me. But in this case why ("00" == true) is true??? Why this time "00" not is 0?

Comment: Cause "00" is not a natural number, i tested your function since php 4 to 8 and always return true